# Using ELKI, having troubles with dimensions higher than 14

Tags: cluster-analysis, dimensions, elki

I'm trying to use SUBCLU in ELKI, but in order to figure things out I've tried DBSCAN, and even KMEANSLloyd, just so I know how to input data with high dimensions. Unfortunately I can only enter up to 14 Dimensions, any higher and the program starts complaining that I've not entered a parameter for "bubble.scaling", even when I quite clearly have. I'm inputting the data by using a .csv file formatted in a similar fashion to the "mouse.csv" tutorial file (which is how I figured out how to enter data with dimensions higher than 1 in the first place). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does not make sense that it starts complaining about the "bubble.scaling" parameter. This indicates it has issues long before running the algorithm, maybe even before loading the data. In fact, it looks as if the JVM gets messed up somehow so that it has issues with the class loader! Please provide a stacktrace, and also try standard *debugging* techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't formatting the CSV file properly. Rather than having a CSV file with just the data in it seperated by spaces for dimensionality, I needed to also include the headers. As I wasn't using randomly generated information and I didn't know the number of clusters beforehand, this is what the CSV looked like.

```
## Size: 10
########################################################
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Although that being said, the examples of high dimensional data they supply don't have these headers but magically work just fine.

Comment: Heaven forbid should MY data work like that though, no MY data gives me an out of bounds java exception.

Comment: I'm always using files without headers, with more than 14 dimensions. All my files "magically work just fine"... sure there isn't some subtle error in your file? Does it work from command line? Any error logged?

Comment: ELKI supports dimensions over 14 without problems, it's part of my daily business. Which version are you using, and please share a stacktrace! ELKI has a highly optimized parser, and it may still contain some issues. It's open source, so you can debug it, too!

Comment: I'm using elki-0.6.5~20141030. I'm also running it on windows using the included .bat file, so I'm not sure if that'll have any effect. I think you might be right about there being a problem somewhere else as half the time it runs fine (I've stopped using .csv files now and I'm using plain .txt files), while the other half the program hangs while trying to visualise. This is what it shows when it hangs after setting debug to true http://imgur.com/gsuBJYt

Comment: The error in the screenshot is when you modify the *parameters* while the algorithm is still running, as far as I can tell. It's a concurrent modification within the MiniGUI parameter table!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Im my case it turned out that my csv file contained only integer columns, which were seen as string data type instead of numeric data type. By setting the dbc.parser to CategoricalDataAsNumberVectorParser, the outofbounds error disappeared.

Comment: What is a fake numeric as opposed to a "really numeric" column?!?

Comment: @HasQUIT--Anony-Mousse: I changed my answer a little to avoid the confusion that was caused by the words "really numeric".